# How to move value from one enum variant to another?

Tags: rust, enums, ownership

I have an enum that represents some state and a value that should be passed from one state to the next state.

```rust
struct MyValue {
    // data
}

enum MyState {
    Before(MyValue),
    After(MyValue),
}
```

Is there a way to write a method for `MyState` that transfers the ownership of `MyValue` from `Before` to `After`?

```rust
impl MyState {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let val = MyValue {};
        MyState::Before(val);
    }
    
    fn change_state(&mut self) {
        let val = todo!(); // move val out of Before into After without cloning the value
        *self = MyState::After(val);
    }
}
```